# Smartface 4.5 crashes with Create Table

Tags: smartface.io

Smartface 4.5 crashes on Android without any error code if you try to create table with following code.
How to create local table with this new version?

```
Data.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testtable;");
Data.execute("Create table testtable (col1 int, col2 int)");
```

Comment: It's a good question I was supposed to ask that question because my applications are force closing because it can't create the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, it will be fixed. 
450 will be updated soon.

Comment: Also IOS simulator crash without any error if you create webclient on project. It is probably cause with the same bug!

Comment: @merve when will the new update will come of smartface?